# Rails: How to modify tests for a nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested, testing

While learning Rails I've created an application with a `Domains` controller nested below a `Customers` controller. I'm using Rails 2.3.4 and it's been a learning experience. I managed to get the below routing set up:

```
    customer_domains GET    /customers/:customer_id/domains(.:format)          {:controller=>"domains", :action=>"index"}
                     POST   /customers/:customer_id/domains(.:format)          {:controller=>"domains", :action=>"create"}
 new_customer_domain GET    /customers/:customer_id/domains/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"domains", :action=>"new"}
edit_customer_domain GET    /customers/:customer_id/domains/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"domains", :action=>"edit"}
     customer_domain GET    /customers/:customer_id/domains/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"domains", :action=>"show"}
                     PUT    /customers/:customer_id/domains/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"domains", :action=>"update"}
                     DELETE /customers/:customer_id/domains/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"domains", :action=>"destroy"}
           customers GET    /customers(.:format)                               {:controller=>"customers", :action=>"index"}
                     POST   /customers(.:format)                               {:controller=>"customers", :action=>"create"}
        new_customer GET    /customers/new(.:format)                           {:controller=>"customers", :action=>"new"}
       edit_customer GET    /customers/:id/edit(.:format)                      {:controller=>"customers", :action=>"edit"}
            customer GET    /customers/:id(.:format)                           {:controller=>"customers", :action=>"show"}
                     PUT    /customers/:id(.:format)                           {:controller=>"customers", :action=>"update"}
                     DELETE /customers/:id(.:format)                           {:controller=>"customers", :action=>"destroy"}
                root        /                                                  {:controller=>"customers", :action=>"index"}
```

However, all tests for the Domains controller are failing due to routing errors.

For example the following test (generated by Rails' resource generator) fails, as do all other tests in the `DomainsControllerTest` class.

```
class DomainsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:domains)
  end
end
```

It fails with the error:

```
No route matches {:action => "index", :controller => "domains"}
```

This makes sense since the default routes no longer exist and the Domains controller requires a `@customer` to be set. I've spent an afternoon looking for the needed change, but almost every site talks about Rspec tests instead of regular Rails tests.

How do I modify the `domains_controller_test.rb` so it will understand the nested resource?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Passing the customer_id with the requests would do. Something like this :-

```
class DomainsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index ,:customer_id=> 1
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:domains)
  end
end
```

Comment: That seems to work, Rishav. Is there any way to DRY this up, instead of passing the id to each separate test?

Comment: Martijn, that's what you're gonna have to do. Your routing must know the customer to work. I suppose you could write a test helper to replace the "get" call that autofills the customer_id part of the hash, but that seems like a bad idea unless you're writing many, many tests against the DomainsController.

Comment: Just want to point out why DRYing this up could be a bad idea b/c it could be hard to read and debug. DRY code is great, but not when it sacrifices readability. In a test, you definitely want to be able to see what's going on. If you can DRY it up without sacrificing readability or adding fragility to the test, do it.

Answer (score 1):

According to your routes, domains don't longer exist outside of the context of a customer. The request needs a `customer_id` for the named routes to match.

The way to do this in your test is:

```
test "should get index" do
  get :index, :customer_id=>joe
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Domains create would be `post :create, :customer_id=>joe`.  The `customer_id` will still be found in the URL for a nested resource.

Answer (score 1):

There is a gem called [nester](https://github.com/adamonduty/nester) that solves this exact problem. It generates methods that give you back a `domains_path` and similar as if your routes weren't nested. When your views and tests reference, for example, `domain_path(domain)`, the routes are expanded to `customer_domain_path(domain.customer, domain)`. There is also a `ActionController::TestCase` helper that adds `:customer_id => @domain.customer` for methods like `get`, `post`, etc.

The default generated functional tests and views work out of the box with this approach. (Disclaimer: I wrote it).